# Makefile target with md5

Tags: makefile

I'm attempting to write a makefile that will asset fingerprint my javascript files. That way I can have infinite cache expiry.

I have a folder called src/. I want to get the javascript files in there, and substitute the names into `app.6b3hj24278b.js`. So I can have a target that way.

Then I was thinking I could use grep to replace instances of the app.js in index.html to the fingerprinted file.

Here's my entire makefile

```
#Variables
APP=application

JS_SRC=src/boot.js
JS_TARGETS =$(patsubst %.js,$(md5sum $JS_SRC),$JS_SRC)
HTMLSRC=index.html
OUTDIR=dist/

.PHONY: all clean

all: html js

js: $(JS_TARGETS)
        cp $(js_src)$(date) $(OUTDIR)

html: $(HTMLSRC)
        cp $(HTMLSRC) $(OUTDIR)

clean:
        rm all
```

```

Particularly I was trying to make `JS_TARGETS` add md5 to the name. What I'm getting is `*** No rule to make target 'S_SRC', needed by 'js'.  Stop.`

Is there a simple way of doing this?. Bonus points if it will wildcard files src/*.js, but If i have to add in my filenames thats okay too.

Also would be great if there was a makefile target that replaces instances of "app.js" to "app.md5sum.js" in the html target.

UPDATE:

For those that may be interested. The makefile I've produced is at this gist
https://gist.github.com/btrepp/164b0153aa9f8d7e258765af7f1c12fc

It scans index.html and finds script references. Fingerprints them, and updates the index.html to match. So I can use infinite cache expiry on any js files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid code.

```
JS_TARGETS =$(patsubst %.js,$(md5sum $JS_SRC),$JS_SRC)
```

There is no function `md5sum`; you want `$(shell md5sum ...)`; but as suggested by the parentheses, it will be evaluated before the `patsubst` runs, and not have useful arguments yet at this point.  Try something like this instead.

```
JS_TARGETS := $(foreach j,$(JS_SRC),$(basename $j).$(word 1,$(shell md5sum $j)).js)
```

The [`foreach` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html) evaluates its last argument only while it loops, so you get the result you want.  The `word` is to extract just the actual checksum from the output of `md5sum`, which includes the file name.

(You also have incomplete bracketing; `$JS_SRC` is equivalent to `$(J)S_SRC` whereas you want `$(JS_SRC)`; and `$(patsubst ...)` does not work like you think it does.)

As for resolving references in the `html`, I would simply generate a `sed` script from the output of `md5sum`.  This is untested, but you should easily find many Stack Overflow questions with this answer (some by myself);

```
md5sum $(JS_SRC) \
| sed 's%^\([0-9a-f]\*\)  \(.*\)\.js$%s/\2\.js/\2.\1.js/g%' \
| sed -f - -i *.html
```

Briefly, we translate the output from `md5sum` into a sequence of `sed` substitution commands, then pass that generated `sed` script to a second instance of `sed`.  As always, `sed` is not entirely standardized, so consult your local `sed` man page for tweaks (in particular, your dialect might or might not want backslashes before the capturing parentheses).  Also, if your `sed` does not like reading a script for `-f` from standard input with `-`, maybe you'll want to generate a temporary file with the `sed` script as a Makefile target instead.

The dollar sign will need to be escaped by doubling it when you put this in a Makefile; this is just for testing at the shell prompt.

Comment: That works great. Though how would I go about copying the file?. I've tried writing something like `$(OUTDIR)/%.js: $(SRCDIR)/%.*.js cp... etc` but I'm having trouble, trick is at that point I dont know/care the md5 in the dependency, but the implicit matching requires I know it.

Comment: You could hack up an associative array with indirect variables, or just generate a hard-coded list of dependencies.  Basically, create a Makefile snippet with the mapping from the target (with the MD5 checksum) from the source (without it) and then `include` it.

Comment: I figured out I could use $(basename $(basename %)).ext  in the dependency list. This strips of the second last extension (which is the md5sum)

Comment: Again, these functions normally run when your makefile is evaluated, not at dependency resolution time. With GNU Make 4, you get a [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) feature which supports your goal, though.

Comment: For better visibility, you should ask a new question if you are still having problems.